# Android App: From realtime Database to firestore - update Data to Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on my first app and am just setting all the frame work up.
That is user sign up via Google, Email, Facebook and saving the data to Firebase.
I started using Realtime Database, which worked fine, but for the proceeding of my project, I think FireStore Cloud would be better suited.

I didnt have much data yet, so it was easy to get it set up.
User signs up or logs in, and if he doesnt exist already, a profile is set up based on the FirebaseAuth Name + Email and some variables I defined ("Nickname", "-"), and a few more.
All good so far. The information is fetched and displayed once the user clicks on his profile. 
Then there is the OPTION TO EDIT some data, like the nickname, the age and the nationality. 
If I update the data directly on firestore and click on profile again, it displays correctly.
BUT if the user enters the information and clicks the button that triggers the update to the firestore cloud, the app crashes. The database, however, also updates correctly...
I tried a lot things, but Im stuck! Thanks a lot for your help!

**MY CODE**

USER CLASS => where the information is stored to the cloud one time, when the user logs in

```
public class User extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String AGE = "Age";
public static final String EMAIL = "Email";
public static final String FULLNAME = "Full name";
public static final String NATIONALITY = "Nationality";
public static final String NICKNAME = "Nickname";
public static final String STATUS = "Status";

private String userEmail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
private String userFullName = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();


public User() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
}

protected void checkFireStoreDatabase() {
    // Create a new user with a first and last name
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference usersDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(userFullName);

    if (usersDocRef != null) {
    } else {
        createNewEntry();
    }
}

public void createNewEntry() {
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference usersDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(userFullName);
    Map<String, Object> userEntry;

    userEntry = new HashMap<>();
    userEntry.put("Full name", userFullName);
    userEntry.put(EMAIL, userEmail);
    userEntry.put("Nickname", "-");
    userEntry.put("Age", "-");
    userEntry.put("Nationality", "-");
    userEntry.put("Status", "Baby monkey");
    db.document(userFullName).set(userEntry, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Document could not be saved");
        }
    });
}
```

USER PROFILE FRAGMENT => where the user can see his information that is stored in the cloud

```
public class UserProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btnEditProfile;

//get firestore database data
private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
private DocumentReference usersDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //DATA FROM FIRESTORE
    displayFirestoreData();

    btnEditProfile = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_user_info);
    btnEditProfile.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_profile, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    //if the button representing the "train now or create workout" fragment is clicked, create this fragment
    if (v.getId() == R.id.edit_user_info) {
        fragment = new EditUserProfileFragment();
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}

public void displayFirestoreData() {
    if (usersDocRef != null) {
    }
        //this.getActivity makes sure the listener only works when in this FragmentActivity
    usersDocRef.addSnapshotListener(this.getActivity(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                String name = documentSnapshot.getString(FULLNAME);
                String email = documentSnapshot.getString(EMAIL);
                String nickname = documentSnapshot.getString(NICKNAME);
                String age = documentSnapshot.getString(AGE);
                String nationality = documentSnapshot.getString(NATIONALITY);
                String status = documentSnapshot.getString(STATUS);

                //setting all the text views in the user profile
                TextView txtProfileName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_section_fullname);
                txtProfileName.setText(name);
                TextView txtProfileEmail = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_section_email);
                txtProfileEmail.setText(email);
                TextView txtProfileNickname = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_section_nickname);
                txtProfileNickname.setText(nickname);
                TextView txtProfileAge = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_section_age);
                txtProfileAge.setText(age);
                TextView txtProfileNationality = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_section_nationality);
                txtProfileNationality.setText(nationality);
                TextView txtProfileStatus = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_section_status);
                txtProfileStatus.setText(status);
            } else if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "An exception occured", e);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

EDIT USER PROFILE FRAGMENT => where the user can enter a new nickname, age or nationality

```
    public class EditUserProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnSaveProfile;

    private EditText editUsername;
    private EditText editAge;
    private EditText editNationality;

    private String username_input;
    private String age_input;
    private String nationality_input;


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //Button to save the profile
        btnSaveProfile = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save_user_info);
        btnSaveProfile.setOnClickListener(this);

        //field that allows changes on the nick name
        editUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_section_edit_nickname);

        //field that allows you to enter the correct age
        editAge = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_section_edit_age);

        //field that allows you to enter your nationality
        editNationality = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_section_edit_nationality);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_profile_edit, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        username_input=  editUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        age_input = editAge.getText().toString().trim();
        nationality_input = editNationality.getText().toString().trim();

        //update Firestore data
        updateFireStoreData(username_input, age_input, nationality_input);
       }

    //update the user entered information to the database, if the strings arent empty
    public void updateFireStoreData(String nicknameUpdate, String ageUpdate, String nationalityUpdate) {
       FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
       FirebaseUser currUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
       DocumentReference userDocRef = db.collection("Users").document(currUser.getDisplayName());

        if (!nicknameUpdate.matches("")) {
            Map<String, Object> dataUpdate = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            dataUpdate.put(NICKNAME, nicknameUpdate);
            userDocRef
                    .set(dataUpdate, SetOptions.merge()).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Document has been saved");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Document could not be saved");
                }
            });
        }
}
```

**ERROR LOG:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: MYAPP, PID: 3992
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at MYAPP.UserProfileFragment$1.onEvent(UserProfileFragment.java:103)
>                         at MYAPP.UserProfileFragment$1.onEvent(UserProfileFragment.java:91)
>                         at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.zza(Unknown Source:45)
>                         at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzd.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevc.zza(Unknown Source:6)
>                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevd.run(Unknown Source:6)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6563)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Firebase database Exception, either a Cloud Firestore Exception. Your Exception tells you clearly what is going on. So you are attempting to use `findViewById()` method `on a null object reference`. This means that `getView()` returns `null`. And this is happening because you are calling that method after you are returning the fragmnet view.

In order to solve this, call those methods before and use `findViewById()` method directly on the view.

Comment: thanks a lot, also just found out that caused it. However, it worked when i had the Firebase Database methods.. I literally had the same code apart from the update, save to database methods. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just would like to find out, why the same getView() call worked before when updating to Realtime DB. But yer, probably should jsut accept that it works now

Comment: Because both were in the same scope.

Comment: okay, sounds legit. So is it the best practice to always initialize TextViews in onCreateView already?

Comment: Yes. And when it comes to Firebase, if you use asynchronous methods, declare and use them within asynchronous methods.